# javascript onkeypress error live Preview text CKEditor without text Area

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor, onkeypress

I have CKEditor WYSIWYG I want to live print the content in another div
But all attempts failed Because the  box is div not textarea
please help .
I used this code

```
var wpcomment = document.getElementById('CKEditordiv');

wpcomment.onkeyup = wpcomment.onkeypress = function(){
    document.getElementById('printdiv').innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Also you add id to body CKEditor

```
<body id="CKEditordiv" contenteditable="true" class="cke_editable cke_editable_themed cke_contents_ltr" spellcheck="false"><p><br></p></body>
```

and print id div

```
<div id="image-holdere"></div>
```

i use this code

http://jsfiddle.net/m7mdq8vs/

Answer (score 0):

Try using code like this one (it's a good starting point):

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {});
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function( evt ) {
    editor.on( 'saveSnapshot', function( e ) {                  
        document.getElementById( 'insert-here' ).innerHTML  = editor.getSnapshot();                 
    });
});         

editor.on( 'key', function( evt ) {
    document.getElementById( 'insert-here' ).innerHTML  =  editor.document.getBody().getHtml();
});
```

You can put is directly on HTML page. If you need just typing you can only use the `key` event if however you need to show what plugins insert, you need to use `saveSnapshot` event as well.